# How to write date conversion condition in javax XPath?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff id="1001" thedate="2013-01-01">
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff id="2001" thedate="2014-01-01">
        <firstname>low</firstname>
        <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
        <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

I need a java code, which can compare dates from XML.
I wrote this java code, but it does not work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File fXmlFile = new File("c:\\tmp\\test.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            String exp = "xs:date(@thedate) &gt; xs:date('2013-05-01')"; //here comes the expression, but it does not work
            System.out.println(selectBooleanValue(nNode,exp));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private static boolean selectBooleanValue(Node node, String xpathString) {
    try {
        XPath xpath = XPATH_FACTORY.get().newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathString);
        boolean result = Boolean.valueOf(expr.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.BOOLEAN).toString());
        return result;
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
private static ThreadLocal<XPathFactory> XPATH_FACTORY = new ThreadLocal<XPathFactory>() {
    @Override
    protected XPathFactory initialValue() {
        return XPathFactory.newInstance();
    };
};
```

I always get "false, false" output, so it does not work. The corresponding output would be: "false, true"

This line is the main question here:

```
String exp = "xs:date(@thedate) &gt; xs:date('2013-05-01')"; //here comes the expression, but it does not work
```

I tried without `xs:` but it is also does not work. I know there are other ways, but I need to solve this problem with that line! What kind of expression should I use to compare date values which are String variables actually?

I tried my code to compare strings, and it is works with it, but I need to compare dates!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

XPath 2.0 which you seem to use has two greater than comparison operators, one is `>`, the other is `gt`. So try the expression `xs:date(@thedate) > xs:date('2013-05-01')` or the expression `xs:date(@thedate) gt xs:date('2013-05-01')`. `&gt;` is only used inside XSLT code to make sure the code is following XML rules, that is not something needed in pure XPath. But I wonder whether you use an XPath 2.0 implementation at all and whether you also do not need to set up a namespace resolver to map the `xs` prefix to the XML schema namespace.

Assuming you have the Java built-in XPath 1.0 implementation all you can do is compare numbers so you could use `number(translate(@thedate, '-', '')) > 20130501`.

Comment: I am sure I suggested the correct XPath 2.0 syntax but as I said, I doubt you use XPath 2.0, I suspect your code always ends up in `catch (XPathExpressionException e) { return false; }` and that is why you get `false`. So make sure you have an XPath 2.0 implementation and you set up the right namespace context to be able to use `xs:date`.

Comment: you are right. where and how can I set the XPath2.0 syntax, and the right namespace in java?

Comment: The Sun respectively Oracle JRE comes with XPath 1.0, to have a XPath 2.0 you need a third party implementation like Saxon 9. I am afraid I can't tell you the right interfaces you need to implement for namespace resolution, if you want to use Saxon then start with http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/xpath-api/jaxp-xpath/.

Comment: @victorio namespaces are a pain in the `javax.xml.xpath` API, I would recommend you go with Saxon 9.x and use its native [s9api](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/package-summary.html), where the [XPathCompiler](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XPathCompiler.html) has a straightforward `declareNamespace` method you can call.